# reactjs: how to show updated state immediately?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs

Hello I am trying to add comment and show the added comment immediately on DOM. However, any word that I type in the form box is not showing in the form box. Then if I press the enter key, it is not sending any POST request. Is there something wrong with how I render , or something wrong with my handleClick(), or both?

this is my handleChange function and how I render previous comments with a loop and the form to add new comments.

```
  handleChange(event) {
    fetch(this.props.url, {method: 'POST'})
    .then((response)=>{
      if (!rosponse.ok) throw Error(response.statusText);
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({
        comments: this.state.comments.concat(data)
      });
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <ul> 
        {this.state.comments.map((comment)=> (
          <li><a href={comment.owner_show_url}>{comment.owner}</a> {comment.text}</li>
        ))}

      </ul>
      <form id="comment-form" onChange = {this.handleChange} >
      <input type="text" value="" name="text" onChange = {this.handleChange}/>
      </form>
      </div>

    );
```

This is the API response if a POST request is sent successfully.

```
{
  "commentid": 8,
  "owner": "username",
  "owner_show_url": "/",
  "postid": 3,
  "text": "Comment"
}
```

Comment: Try sending the number of likes from the server in case of success (both for POST/DELETE) request and set the result using setState. Your like button is updating immediately because you have changed the state and it has caused re-rendering of the component. If you are still having a doubt do mention the same and I will try explaining the same with an example.

Comment: Also componentDidMount only get's called once when the component has finished mounting, this is the reason your GET gets called only once and your app performs properly during the refresh but misbehaves during updation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I changed num_likes in a similar manner as I changed the boolean and it worked! However, now I am trying to add comments and I am implementing my function in the same way but the <form> in my render() is not working at all... any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Sure. Let me have a look at the code.

Comment: Your handleChange is getting called but not since it is not binded you are not able to access the state. Either bind your handleChange function or try converting the function to arrow function and that would be like this handleChange = (event) => {}

Comment: do you mean [this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);] in the constructor?

Comment: Yeah. Give me a minute and I will post a working answer for your better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is getting called but since it is not bound, it is not able to recognize the **state** object because of which undefined object error is thrown while trying to access **this.state**

A normal function has **this** context of its own.

You can either **bind the function** in the constructor or use an **arrow function** which does not have any context of its own.

**Solution 1**

Bind your function

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(event) {
 // your code here
}
```

**Solution 2**

Change the function to arrow function

```
handleChange = (event) => {
 // Your code here
}
```

You can also find the solution with the code provided by you in the below-codesandbox link.

[image: Edit reverent-star-5uktu]